# Not incrementing static variable in derived class

Tags: c++

I made class Head and class Derived from class Head. What should I do to have static (like a counter of object of class Head) variable which not increment in derived class.

In Head class:

```
class Head{
    private:
         static int counter;
         string name;
         int amount;
    public:
         Head(const string& n):name(n){
             counter++;
         }
};
int Head::counter=0;
```

and in class Derived:

```
class Derived: public Head{
    public:
       Derived(const string& n):Head(n){};
};
```

My target is to not increment counter when I create new object of class Derived.
What should I use? Virtual class, can someone explain me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: its not really clear, do you maybe want to not increment the counter when you create an object of the class Derived? (you wrote Head in the text)

Comment: Why do you want this behaviour? When an object of Derived is created you actually also do create an object of class Head (as part of the Derived object)

Comment: yup, I dont want to increment counter when I creadte object of Derived class, sorry

Comment: My derived class got an extra behaviour metods which create different object, just few elements are same.

Comment: Well you could add another parameter like a bool and default it to true.  If the variable is true when executing the body of the constructor then increment else do nothing.  Then in the derived class call the constructor but pass in false.  You could also have this as a protected constructor so only derived classes can call it.

Comment: I see two options: 1) Make the class that increases the counter a seperate subclass of head. 2) decrease the counter in the Derived constructor

Comment: Please fix all of the errors in your code. Missing semicolons at the end of your classes, you're not even inheriting from `Head` in `Derived`; `counter` is not `static` either and it is declared `const`, which goes completely against what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Make a conditional in your constructor (completely untested):

```
class Head{
    private:
         static int counter;
         string name;
         int amount;
    public:
         Head(const string& n, bool increment = true):name(n) {
             if (increment) {
                 counter++;
             }
         }
};
int Head::counter=0;
```

and in class Derived:

```
class Derived: public Head{
    public:
       Derived(const string& n):Head(n, false){};
};
```

Comment: It was just meant to work, I am unaware of why the OP wants this behavior and maybe a lot could be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

Segregate ctors, add another protected ctor for derived classes?

```
struct Base {
    Base(const string &);
protected:
    Base(nullptr_t, const string &);
};

struct Derived: Base {
    Derived(const string &s): Base(nullptr, s) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just **overload** the `constructor` by changing the **signature**.

```
class Head{
    private:
     static int counter;
     string name;
     int amount;
    public:
     Head(){}   
     Head(const string& n):name(n) {count++;}
     Head(const string& n,int a):name(n) {}
}
int Head::counter=0;



class Derived{
    public:
       Derived(const string& n):Head(n,1){};
}
```